# nosuchmethoderror of method valueToString in JsonObject class using temboo

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror, temboo

I am making an android app where user will get `newsfeed/timeline/dashboard` from different social media accounts. I used `Temboo` to implement this.

During `Oauth` it gave me an error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method valueToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/json/JSONObject; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONObject' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

my app crashes all the time.
i tried their tutorial app, it gave the same error. 
Need help :(

P.S.: if there is any other way that i could implement this please share. I am new to development.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace of the exception and at least the part of the code that caused it.

Comment: can you also add the code segment where the crash is occuring.

Comment: how can i record stack trace?

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an org.json.jar in your class library? It's possible that java is picking up an older version of the org.json.JSONObject which does not implement the method you need. The Temboo SDK bundles those classes, but in your case java might be finding some other version of that library before loading the Temboo library. Removing the other jar that has org.json classes in it or making sure it is loaded after the Temboo jar may solve the problem. It could also be that another jar of yours embeds org.json classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

***I had an extra json lib jar file included in the project, which is not needed because it is already provided by the Android Framework...***

Answer (score 0):

It seems android use it's own `JSONObject` located in `core-libart.jar` and not overrided by the version in `JSON-java.jar`

Work around: change `JSONObject.valueToString(obj)` to `new JSONObject(obj).toString()`

which has the same result and available in both versions.